# Upper and Lower bounds on discrete zero sums and products equal to one

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

What methods can be used to find upper and lower bounds for a sequence of non-zero complex numbers b in terms of each other given they obey the following conditions:
$$\sum_{n=1}^m b_n=0\qquad \text{ and }\qquad \prod_{n=1}^m b_n=1\qquad \text{ and }\qquad \sum_{n=1}^m 1/b_n=0$$

The only solution I have found to this sequence B was $$b_n=-(-1)^m(c_m)^n$$ where $c_m$ is the mth root of unity. Are there others or at least bounds on their solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose them arbitrarily
for $n=1$ to $m-2$.

Then want
$0
=\sum_{n=1}^m b_n
=\sum_{n=1}^{m-2} b_n+b_{m-1}+b_m
$
and
$1
=\prod_{n=1}^m b_n
=\prod_{n=1}^{m-2} b_n\cdot b_{m-1}\cdot b_m
$.

Letting
$u=\sum_{n=1}^{m-2} b_n,
v=\prod_{n=1}^{m-2} b_n,
x=b_{m-1},
y=b_m
$,
this becomes
$0=u+x+y,
1=vxy
$.

Solve this for $x$ and $y$
in terms of $u$ and $v$.

As to bounds, I don't know.